# Trouble installing Canon imageCLASS MF4450

Tags: printing

I am new to Linux and just installed the latest version of Ubuntu on a Dell Vostro model 260S.  I am trying to complete the process by installing the printer I have.  It is a Canon imageCLASS MF4450.  I have tried everything suggested by Canon and followed the guidance of other online documents for installing printers in Ubuntu.  Nothing has worked.  Can anyone help?  I can and will follow instructions to the letter.

Comment: have you tried the OEM specific drivers? UFR II Printer Driver for Linux Version 3.00  I own both devices, and can vouch for them working properly. Do you have CUPS installed? What desktop environment are you using?